# Tengo un archivo de texto con Strings y Doubles. Quiero pasarlo a un TreeMap<String,ArrayList<Double>>

Tags: java, archivo

Explico: Tengo un archivo de texto, por ejemplo:

```
lucas
1234.23456
123.1451
25.54
5
david
4253.53
346.654
2346.436
```

Me gustaría que mi programa guarde en un *TreeMap* (o cualquier otra colección, no tiene que ser necesariamente TreeMap) un nombre junto a su *ArrayList* de *doubles*.

```
{lucas=[1234.23456, 123.1451, 25.54, 5], david=[4253.53, 346.654, 2346.436]}...
```

Como veis, cada vez que encuentra un *String* (nombre), creará una nueva entrada en el *TreeMap*.

De momento llevo esto:

```
package lectorcodigobarras;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Lectorcodigobarras {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(leerFichero());
    }

    
    public static TreeMap<String,ArrayList<Double>> leerFichero(){
        TreeMap<String,ArrayList<Double>> lista = null;
        ArrayList<Double> pesos;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            lista = new TreeMap<String,ArrayList<Double>>();
            pesos = new ArrayList<Double>();
            fis = new FileInputStream("datos.dat");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8"));
            String line;
            String nombre = null;
            while (reader.ready()) {
                do{
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    if (esDouble(line)){
                        System.out.println("double: " + line);
                        pesos.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("string: " + line);
                        nombre = line;
                    }
                } while(!esDouble(line));
                lista.put(nombre, new ArrayList<Double>(pesos));
                pesos.clear();
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if (fis != null){
                try{
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error al cerrar el fichero");
                }
            }
            if (reader != null){
                try{
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error al cerrar el reader");
                }
            }
        }
        return lista;
    }
    
    public static boolean esDouble(String s){
        try{
            Double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Lo que me devuelve es:

```
string: lucas
double: 1293.145
double: 1241.643
double: 1434.5
double: 234234.67
string: pepe
double: 1234
double: 1234
double: 235
double: 256
{lucas=[234234.67], david=[256.0]}
```

Es decir, sólo el último *double* de cada uno.

> (Ignorar la parte donde pone "string:" o "double:" ya que sólo la he puesto para comprobar ciertas cosas)

Si alguien sabe cómo arreglar esto, lo agradecería mucho.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno según veo el *do while* que utilizas está por demás, te seria mucho más fácil hacer los siguiente dentro del *while*:

```
line = reader.readLine(); // Leer la linea
if (esDouble(line)) { // Verificar si es double
    pesos.add(Double.parseDouble(line)); // Si es double adicionamos a pesos
} else {
    nombre = line; // Si es string simplemente asignamos el nombre
    pesos.clear(); // Y limpiamos la variable pesos
}
```

Lo que necesitas es recorrer todos los campos que tienes en tu archivo **`datos.dat`** cosa que con el *do while* realizabas iteraciones extra que no te llevaban a ningún lado.

El código completo quedaría así:

```
package lectorcodigobarras;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Lectorcodigobarras {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(leerFichero());
    }
    
    public static TreeMap<String,ArrayList<Double>> leerFichero(){
        TreeMap<String,ArrayList<Double>> lista = null;
        ArrayList<Double> pesos;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            lista = new TreeMap<String,ArrayList<Double>>();
            pesos = new ArrayList<Double>();
            fis = new FileInputStream("datos.dat");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8"));
            String line;
            String nombre = null;
            while (reader.ready()) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if (esDouble(line)) {
                    pesos.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
                } else {
                    nombre = line;
                    pesos.clear();
                }
                lista.put(nombre, new ArrayList<Double>(pesos));
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if (fis != null){
                try{
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error al cerrar el fichero");
                }
            }
            if (reader != null){
                try{
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error al cerrar el reader");
                }
            }
        }
        return lista;
    }
    
    public static boolean esDouble(String s){
        try{
            Double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Salida:

> {david=[4253.53, 346.654, 2346.436], lucas=[1234.23456, 123.1451, 25.54, 5.0]}